# формат времени в json

Tags: c#, json, datetime

Есть json, в котором есть дата и время начала некоего события, заданная числом, например 1461578400000. Как тут может быть зашифровано время начала? Никак не пойму, `TimeSpan.FromMiliseconds()` выдает странный результат, `DateTime.FromBinary()` тоже. Никак не могу разобраться

Comment: Приведите полный json. Как именно записано время? Вероятно `\/Date(1461578400000)\/`?

Comment: нет, просто "t" : "1335205592410"

Comment: Это у Вас, судя по всему, Unix timestamp, с добавлением миллисекунд. То есть, `1461578400000` соответствует времени `25.04.2016 10:00:00.000 UTC`, а `1335205592410` — это `23.04.2012 18:26:32.410`.

Answer (score 3):

Каким именно десериализатором JSON пользуетесь?

Вообще, формат даты/времени в JSON не стандартизирован. Поэтому в разных сериализаторах они различаются.

Например, ваши значения понимает System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer из библиотеки System.Web.Extensions.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();  

var dt1 = jss.Deserialize<DateTime>(@"""\/Date(1461578400000)\/""");
Console.WriteLine(dt1); // 25.04.2016 10:00:00

var dt2 = jss.Deserialize<DateTime>(@"""\/Date(1335205592410)\/""");
Console.WriteLine(dt2); // 23.04.2012 18:26:32
```

---

Как отметил **Yaant**, это Unix timestamp. В .NET версии 4.6 появились новые методы, в частности, [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var dto1 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1461578400000);
var dto2 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1335205592410);
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот json, очевидно, генерируется на javascript, и включает в себя милисекунды. Поэтому, при конвертации получается дата в далёком будущем.
Для того, чтобы получить корректную дату, нужно разделить таймстамп на 1000 и округлить до целого числа, чтобы получились привычные секунды.

Comment: Так это получится 405 часов... и что? Как мне это вывести красиво? Это же несколько дней типа... значит надо от какого-то дня что ли вести отсчет?

Comment: Подождите, какой отсчет, какие часы, куда вывести? Откуда взялось 405? Timestamp - это метка времени, в ней невозможно указать _промежуток_.

Comment: если разделить это число на 1000 потом на 60 потом еще раз на 60 то получим 405 часов примерно... Аа, значит это не промежуток, а отметка. И как ее перевести в хорошее представление?

Comment: Разумеется, делить на 60 ничего не нужно. По поводу того, как вывести, я подсказать, к сожалению не могу. Задайте отдельный вопрос по этому поводу (только не забудьте указать, какой смысл вы вкладываете в термин "хорошее представление"). А ещё лучше просто воспользуйтесь поисковиком, наверняка, вам требуется что-то стандартное.

Comment: Ясное дело, что стандартное, вот только проблема в том, что я не знаю, что именно нужно и как мне привести это длинное число к виду например 12:40

Comment: Что такое 12:40? Timestamp же содержит и дату.  
Теперь, когда мы разобрались с милисекундами, задайте отдельный вопрос по форматированию, специалисты вам помогут сформулировать и дадут ответ.